# How can i set a height for a background header

Tags: html, css

I want to do something like this https://www.buylandingpagedesign.com/example/save-money-on-mortgage-consultant-business-service-lead-gen-effective-landing-page-design-017-th.jpg

But, I can't set the size to the background image and I don't know why, this is what I have tried so far:

Here is my code *(please insert your image in `background-image:`):*

```css
.Header {
  background-image: url('../img/header-2.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.Header-title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  font-size: 5em;
}
.Header-description {
  padding: 0 .5em;
}
```

```html
<nav class="Menu">
  <ul class="Menu-list">
    <li class="Menu-item">Inicio</li>
    <li class="Menu-item">Productos</li>
    <li class="Menu-item">Servicios</li>
    <li class="Menu-item">Contacto</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<header class="Header">
  <h1 class="Header-title">Toncan Digital</h1>
</header>
```

Can you help with this please?

**EDIT**:

You can do this with only doing something like

```
header {
    height: 500px; // or more if you want
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover; // or other, depends of the image and what you want
}
```

[more options on background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Comment: So you want the header to be the height of your bg image...you can only do that by setting the height manually.

Comment: that doesnt work, i dont know why